# How to find number of subgraphs of complete bipartite

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many subgraphs does $K_{4,6}$ have? Is the question asking to find all possible combinations of vertices and edges? If yes, the number of subsets of 4 vertices is $2^4$ but then I'm not sure how to count the combination of vertices.

EDIT: the answer given is $\sum_{j=0}^{4} \sum_{k=0}^{6} \binom{4}{j} \binom{6}{k} 2^{jk}$ can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the particular definition of "subgraph" that you're using.  Is it subgraphs on the same vertex set (i.e. just throwing away edges)?  Then Numeri's answer covers it.

Is it number of induced subgraphs?  That is, are we only interested in graphs obtained by throwing out vertices?  Then it is simply a matter of choosing which vertices to throw out, so you get $2^{10}$ ways here (if you count the graph as a subgraph of itself) or $2^{10}-1$ otherwise.

Are you allowed to throw away either vertices or edges?  Clearly any edge attached to a removed vertex must be removed.  To look at this, I suggest you consider first removing $k_1$ vertices from one part and $k_2$ from the other; how many edges are left after you do that?  How many ways can you choose a further subset of these to remove?

Answer (score 1):

One way to understand the answer:

First, we pick the vertices in our subgraph. There are $4 \choose j$ ways ($0\leq j \leq 4$) to choose the vertices we want from the first partite set and $6 \choose k$ ways ($0 \leq k \leq 6$) for the second.

Now we choose the edges. Of course it doesn't make sense to choose edges whose end-vertices have not been chosen so we first look at the induced subgraph $K_{j,k}$. (i.e. take the $j$ and $k$ vertices we have chosen and only keep the edges between them.)

As @KReiser rightly pointed out there are $jk$ edges in this graph $K_{j,k}$. (We only need to start at one partite set to uniquely determine the number of edges. There are j possible starting vertices and k possible ending vertices, hence $jk$.)

For each edge, we either choose to include it in our subgraph or not include it (i.e. 2 choices.) Hence we have $2^{jk}$ ways to choose the edges.

We multiply these choices for the vertices and edges and sum them over all $j,k$ to get all possible ways to obtain the subgraph. (i.e. the answer $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{j=4} \sum_{k=0}^{k=6} {4 \choose j} {6 \choose k} 2^{jk}$.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find the number of combinations of edges (connected to the proper vertices, of course).

In order to see this, note that a subgraph is the set of the edges included. Each edge is either in the subgraph or it isn't. This means that the number of subgraphs of a graph is equal to $2^{NumOfEdges}$. In the complete bipartite graph $K_{r,s}$, the number of edges is $rs$, so the number of subgraphs of $K_{r,s}$ is $2^{rs}$.

So, the number of subgraphs in $K_{4,6}$ is $2^{4*6} = 2^{24} = 16777216$.

Did I answer your question?

Comment: The situation is a bit more complicated; if you only count edge combinations once, then you can't tell how many vertices it has, but of course a subgraph of $K_{4,6}$ with one edge can have anywhere between 2 and 24 vertices.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry! :)

Comment: How did you know that the number of edges in a complete bipartite graph $K_{a, b}$ is $2^{a*b}$ ? I don't know that theorem.

Comment: Careful- the number of edges in $K_{a,b}$ is $ab$, not $2^{ab}$. Why? Each edge is uniquely specified by one vertex on the left (there are $a$ of these) and one vertex on the right (there are $b$ of these), so there are $ab$ edges in $K_{a,b}$.